# how to get data from asyncstorage without on press in react native

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I want to `AsyncStorage` save data in variable without `onPress` , show data on open app screen

code:

```
const AppScreen = () => {
   var getusername = async () => {
      await AsyncStorage.getItem('name');
   };
   return (
      <Text>{getusername}</Text>
   );
};
export default AppScreen;
```

Comment: Fetch your data > save it as State > React Native refreshes the component if the state changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use react hooks, in particular, useEffect hook to call the function as the app launches

```
const appScreen = () => { var getusername = async () => { await AsyncStorage.getItem('token'); };};

useEffect(() => { appScreen ();}, []);
```